# Querying using a column from a different table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, netsuite

Here is the initial SQL query:

```
SELECT  a.displaynamewithhierarchy as account_name,
        BUILTIN.DF(a.accttype) as account_type,
        t.id as internal_id,
        BUILTIN.DF(t.type) as transaction_type,
        t.trandate as transaction_date,
        BUILTIN.DF(t.postingperiod) as period,
        BUILTIN.CONSOLIDATE(tl.amount, 'INCOME', 'DEFAULT', 'DEFAULT', 1, t.postingperiod, 1) as amount,
        BUILTIN.DF(t.currency) as currency,
        tl.debitforeignamount as amount_debit_foreign,
        tl.creditforeignamount as amount_credit_foreign
FROM transaction t
LEFT JOIN transactionline tl on t.id = tl.transaction
LEFT JOIN transactionaccountingline tal on tl.id = tal.transactionline and t.id = tal.transaction
LEFT JOIN account a on tal.account = a.id
WHERE t.tranid = 'JE2012020'
```

I would like to change `t.postingperiod` (from the BUILTIN.CONSOLIDATE() function) and use the posting period ID (this field would be the `id` in postingperiod table) of the `t.trandate`.

Here is how postingperiod table looks:
[Posting Period Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWeX2.png)

Any idea on how to modify the query?

Comment: If you want to include yet another table (POSTINGPERIOD) into the FROM clause, you'd (OUTER?) **JOIN** it to other table(s) ON common column(s). From what you posted, I'm not sure which table(s) is POSTINGPERIOD joined to nor via which column(s).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to join in that table and use its columns in your `SELECT` list where you want.  Based on your table structure, probably join like this:

```
INNER JOIN postingperiod pp 
  ON t.trandate BETWEEN pp.startdate AND pp.enddate + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND 
  AND pp.isquarter='F'
```